# Twilio Video used with Ionic Framework iOS app error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, twilio-video

I am trying to develop an iOS video chat app using Twilio video.  I have the private descriptions for mic/camera set in the info.plist.  This app works as expected if i run it in browser on the desktop.

When i deploy it to an iPhone, it asks the standard "Do you want to allow X to use your camera and microphone?". I click "Ok".  Nothing happens.  It displays the preview video fine.  It does not display the remote participants video, or send my video to the remote participant.

In xcode it displays these errors:

> [warn] - 2022-02-15T16:12:40.396Z warn [PeerConnectionV2 #1:
> 7f7c53b3-0c6b-4ef0-8058-bf761a3a90fd] Calling setLocalDescription with
> an RTCSessionDescription of type "offer" failed with the error "Failed
> to set local offer sdp: max-bundle is used but no bundle group
> found.". {}
>
> [warn] - 2022-02-15T16:12:40.397Z warn [PeerConnectionV2 #1:
> 7f7c53b3-0c6b-4ef0-8058-bf761a3a90fd] The SDP was v=0
>
> o=- 1766372702324133410 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
>
> s=-
>
> t=0 0
>
> a=extmap-allow-mixed
>
> a=msid-semantic: WMS
>
> [warn] - 2022-02-15T16:12:40.397Z warn [connect #1] event
> {"elapsedTime":380,"group":"media","level":"warning","name":"error","timestamp":1644941560397,"payload":{"message":"Calling
> setLocalDescription with an RTCSessionDescription of type "offer"
> failed","code":53400,"context":"{"error":"Failed to set local offer
> sdp: max-bundle is used but no bundle group
> found.","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1766372702324133410 2 IN IP4
> 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic:
> WMS\r\n"}"}}
>
> [error] - 2022-02-15T16:12:40.398Z error [connect #1] createAndOffer()
> failed: {"message":"Client is unable to create or apply a local media
> description","code":53400,"name":"TwilioError","line":72850,"column":32,"sourceURL":"capacitor://localhost/vendor.js","stack":"TwilioError@capacitor://localhost/vendor.js:72850:32\nMediaClientLocalDescFailedError@capacitor://localhost/vendor.js:72632:32\n@capacitor://localhost/vendor.js:60685:67\nonInvoke@capacitor://localhost/vendor.js:134243:39\n@capacitor://localhost/polyfills.js:453:53\n@capacitor://localhost/polyfills.js:1611:41\nonInvokeTask@capacitor://localhost/vendor.js:134230:43\n@capacitor://localhost/polyfills.js:498:61\ndrainMicroTaskQueue@capacitor://localhost/polyfills.js:913:46\npromiseReactionJob@[native
> code]"}

Im using Ionic 6.3, and twilio-video 2.9.1.  Is this related to a permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a byproduct of an earlier error in the Twilio project.  Initially on build, twilio would give the error:

> Error: node_modules/twilio-video/tsdef/VideoProcessor.d.ts:3:34 -
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.

Initially, I got around this by declaring a type 'any'.  Wrong.  Instead add the @types/offscreencanvas directly to my VideoProcessor.d.ts.

Now my posted error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue with an Ionic/Cordova project. Everything works just fine on Android but iOS displays the same errors as yours.

It seems to be a WebRTC problem and the way iOS uses WKWebView.

If you are using Capacitor this is a good approach:
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1057#issuecomment-1022375757
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-webrtc.js/pull/133#issuecomment-971623438